# FFmpeg text is not displayed in my streamed video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, arm, orange-pi

on orangepi PC (armbian os) have installed Ffmpeg. I have followed the example in one previous post on how to add text into the stream but I don't get any text in my video..

ffserver.conf

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000
CustomLog -

<Feed monitoring1.ffm>
File /tmp/monitoring1.ffm
FileMaxSize 50M
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Feed>

<Stream monitoring1.mjpg>
Feed monitoring1.ffm
Format mpjpeg
VideoCodec mjpeg
VideoFrameRate 22
VideoBufferSize 80
VideoSize 720x264
NoAudio
</Stream>


# Redirect index.html to the appropriate site

<Redirect index.html>
URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

I start a ffmpeg as:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
ffmpeg -i rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=/home/projekt/StreamTest/DejaVuSans.ttf: \
text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=36: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: \
boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy http://localhost:8090/monitoring1.ffm
```

[image]

this is the result but the text is missing

[image]

thank you

Comment: Can you show full console output?

Comment: Here is a complete log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Z9wNTXyUEebDdSYzVydVVnS2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is second log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Z9wNTXyUEeZ21zSDMxdnp5a28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try it again with **-override_ffserver** option?

Comment: Btw, this console command works just fine : `ffmpeg -i rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=ariblk.ttf: text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=36: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" -y output.mp4` .

Comment: Tryed to stream in file and is working. But I would like to diplay the embeded text in my stream http://localhost:8090/monitoring1.ffm (is this possible)?

Comment: Did you use **-override_ffserver** option while streaming to your ffserver?

Comment: Hi, If I put -override_ffserver before -vf then I get this kind of error: av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer
Error writing trailer of http://localhost:8090/monitoring1.ffm: Connection reset by peerframe=    2 fps=0.0 q=4.6 Lsize=      12kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate= 611.9kbits/s speed=3.57x
video:4kB audio:9kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!  If you need adittional log please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Your issue seems related to ffserver and I do not have much experience with it. You may want to check logs from ffserver to get more info on the issue, your ffmpeg version and ffserver version might be incompatible.

Comment: Will try to ask on ffmpeg forum.. It's strange because the application is installed with apt-get install ffmpeg

Comment: found the same question here: https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-September/017309.html

Comment: Have tryed this with "pipe" options in linux: ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 32 -i rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4 -framerate 30 -vf "drawtext=text=TESTTEST :fontfile=fontfile=/home/projekt/StreamTest/Robot-Black.ttf: y=((h)/2):x=(mod(5*n\,w+tw)-tw): fontcolor=red: fontsize=24: shadowx=-5: shadowy=-15" -f flv pipe:1 | ffmpeg -i pipe:0  http://localhost:8090/monitoring1.ffm

It's slow and quality is poor but the text is present in streamed video..